# Access internal tensors and add a new node to a tflite model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am fairly new to TensorFlow and TensorFlow Lite. I have followed the tutorials on how to quantize and convert the model to fixed point calculations using `toco`. Now I have a `tflite` file which is supposed to perform only fixed point operations. I have two questions

1. How do I test this in python? How do i access all the operations and results in the tflite file?
2. Is there a way to add a new node or operation in this tflite file? If so how?

I would be really grateful if anyone could guide me.

Thanks and Regards,
Abhinav George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a new node or operation in this tflite file? If so how?

Unfortunately, **no**, and it is actually a *good thing*. TF-Lite was designed to be extremely light yet effective, using mapped files, flat buffers, static execution plan and so on to decrease memory footprint. The cost of that is that you loose any flexibility of TensorFlow.

TF-Lite is a framework for deployment. However, earlier on [Google IO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByJnpbDd-zc), the TF team mentioned the possibility of on-device training, so maybe some kind of flexibility will be available in the future, but not now.

---

> How do I test this in python? How do i access all the operations and results in the tflite file?

You **cannot** access all internal operations, only inputs and outputs. The reason is simple: *the internal tensors wouldn't be saved, since the memory sections for them are also used for other operations* (which is why the memory footprint of it is so low).

If you just want to see the outputs, you can use the Python API as below (the code is self explanatory):

```python
import pprint
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import interpreter as interpreter_wrapper

# Load the model and allocate the static memory plan
interpreter = interpreter_wrapper.Interpreter(model_path='model.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# print out the input details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
print('input_details:')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(input_details)

# print out the output details
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print('output_details:')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(output_details)

# set input (img is a `numpy array`)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)

# forward pass
interpreter.invoke()

# get output of the network
output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

---

> What if I call `interpreter.get_tensor` for non-input and non-output tensors?

You will not get the actual data that contained in that tensor after execution of the corresponding operation. As mentioned earlier, the memory section for tensors are shared with other tensors for maximum efficiency.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for pointing it out. I wanted to quantize my graph completely such that it performs only fixed point operations and wanted to manipulate the results of few of the operations. Are you aware of any other method to do it in tensorflow?

Comment: Well, if you have a small number of specific operations you want to monitor, you can add them to `outputs` (TF-Lite supports models with multiple outputs)

Comment: Yes, i was thinking on the same lines but I would be able to only monitor them and cannot manipulate it and feed it back into the model right?

Comment: @AbhinavGeorge yeah, but you can make a small hack: divide your model into several parts (each will be converted to a separate `*.tflite` file), so that you can take inner tensors, do some manipulation on them, and feed them further. Look in the directions of [`tf.contrib.graph_editor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/graph_editor) to do such graph surgery.

Comment: I did the same when I squeezed a Multi-Tasking model to device, where the decision on what route to execute depended on other outputs of the model.

Comment: thank you very much. I shall surely take up your advice.